# <identifier> expected in HackerRank code

Tags: java

I have been trying this code on hackerRank, and I get the following error.

```
Solution.java:36: error: <identifier> expected
  System.out.print(ans);
                  ^
Solution.java:36: error: <identifier> expected
  System.out.print(ans);
                      ^
2 errors
```

code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = scan.nextInt(); 
  scan.close();
  String ans="";

  // if 'n' is NOT evenly divisible by 2 (i.e.: n is odd)
  if(n%2==1){
     ans = "Weird";
  }

   else if (n%2==0)//even no
       {
       if(n>2 && n<=5)
      ans="Not Wierd";
       }

        if(n>6 && n<20)
            {
               ans="Wierd";
             }
        else 
        {
     ans="Not Wierd";
           }


  }
  System.out.print(ans);
}
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Here, it's a good practice to upvote certain answers that you deem helpful, and if you can, to mark them so. There's no obligation to do this, but it does help users to rise up through the ranks, or sometimes, simply to feel helpful :)

Comment: If you format your code properly, the cause of this error will become obvious to you.

Answer (score 0):

move your `System.out.print(ans);` up a line so that it is before `}`:

```
  System.out.print(ans);
}
```

As it stand right now, your `System.out` code is outside of `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 }
  System.out.print(ans);
```

to

```
   System.out.print(ans);
}
```

If you correct your indentation it might be easier to spot

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent your code properly. Then you can see clearly structure of blocks. Your `System.out` outside the main method. cut that line and paste it in one `}`.

If you look at the same code properly indented at a glance you will understand whats happening, like below:

```
public class B {
    if(n%2==1){
        ans = "Weird";
    }else if (n%2==0){//even no
        if(n>2 && n<=5)
            ans="Not Wierd";
    }

    if(n>6 && n<20){
        ans="Wierd";
    }else{
        ans="Not Wierd";
    }

    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `ans` doesn't exist in the scope where you are trying to print it.

Please do proper indentation to the code while debugging to better understand the issue.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Solution {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = scan.nextInt();
  scan.close();
  String ans = "";

  // if 'n' is NOT evenly divisible by 2 (i.e.: n is odd)
  if (n % 2 == 1) {
   ans = "Weird";
  } 
  else if (n % 2 == 0) //even no
  {
   if (n > 2 && n <= 5)
    ans = "Not Wierd";
  }

  if (n > 6 && n < 20) {
   ans = "Wierd";
  } 
  else {
   ans = "Not Wierd";
  }
 }
 System.out.print(ans);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java If-Else solution can be.

```
{ 
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();            
        String ans="";
        if(n%2==1){ans = "Weird";}
        else if(n >= 2 && n <= 5){ans ="Not Weird";}
        else if(n >= 6 && n <= 20){ ans = "Weird";}
        else if(n>20){ans = "Not Weird";}

        System.out.println(ans);

    }
}
}
```